# How to extract records from a worksheet into a seperate worksheet using VLOOKUPS and IF's

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, vlookup

Worksheet1:

[Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AYT9.png)

[New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu2kD.png)

Worksheet 1 has licences with 6 columns of information - two being the start and end date.

I need a method of extracting all the records that are within 90 days before the expiry date- the idea being I want a separate alert page

I have done a IF statement that is on the end of the columns that just prints 1 if date is hits the alert criteria or 0 if not...The idea now in Worksheet2 I need some sort of VLOOKUP and IF to extract those records automatically.

How would I do this?

```
=IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(TODAY(),H5,"d"),91)<90,1,0)
```

Comment: Can you use a macro for that or do you need excel formulas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While use of Pivot table or VBA macro is recommended in such cases, if you absolutely need to use the formula then you may use the below trick.

You already have the Binary column. Now, add another column say Cumulative Binary that will sum all the 1's till the current row using a `SumIf` formula as shown in the screenshot below (it is fine if some numbers are repeated because of 0's)

[image]

The formula in I3 in my workbook is
    =SUMIF(H$3:H3,1,H$3:H3)
and you may adjust it as per your needs.

Now, it is easy since each row has a unique number, we could use `Vlookup` or like I have done here i.e. use `Offset` function which simply matches the value in the "Lookup Column" to the value in "Cumulative Binary" column and returns the rows that match.

[image]

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET($F$2,MATCH(M3,$I$3:$I$9,0),0,1,2),"")
```

Please note that it is an array formula as I need to return multiple columns (2 here). So, I selected two columns N,O as shown in the screenshot wrote the formula and used Ctrl+Shift+Enter (instead of Enter). Then I simply dragged the formula down. You may want to adjust it as per your needs by including more columns.

Comment: For some the reason the code is skipping - as in the data that should be extracted is not being extracted

Comment: Can you share more screenshots or perhaps type out the formulas here? It may be because of the ranges and how they are being selected like for example using '$' to lock the range when it may not be needed etc.

Comment: Should be on a new worksheet but I am just testing :)

Comment: In your new image, I see that offset is from $B$2. Change it to $B$1 and it will work. The reason being, match returns the position of the matched value and offset navigates to that position starting one below.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use VBA, you may write some code like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyCloseToExpiration()
    Dim rngSource As Range: Set rngSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Resize(LastRow(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")) - 1, 9)
    Dim rngDestinationTopLeft As Range: Set rngDestinationTopLeft = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(LastRow(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")) + 1, 1)
    Dim datLimit As Date: datLimit = DateAdd("d", 90, Date)

    CopyBeforeDate rngSource, rngDestinationTopLeft, datLimit
End Sub

Public Sub CopyBeforeDate(rngSource As Range, rngDestinationTopLeft As Range, datLimit As Date)
    Dim lngOffset As Long: lngOffset = 0
    Dim rngRow As Range: For Each rngRow In rngSource.Rows
        If rngRow.Cells(1, 8).Value < datLimit Then
            rngDestinationTopLeft.offset(lngOffset, 0).Resize(rngRow.Rows.Count, rngRow.Columns.Count).Value = rngRow.Value
            lngOffset = lngOffset + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Function LastRow(ewsSheet) As Long
    With ewsSheet
        Dim lngResult As Long: lngResult = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    LastRow = lngResult
End Function
```

You have to put the above into a new Module, customize it (e.g. replace "Sheet1" with the name of you worksheet's actual name), and run it (You can place the caret on the sub CopyCloseToExpiration and hit F5 or place a button somewhere and call this function from its event handler).